# Syntax error while trying to move files using a FOR loop

Tags: batch

I am attempting to loop through all the files in the "folder" folders in the specified folder, and move them to a different one.

I have this code:

```
@ECHO OFF
FOR /R C:\Users\user\Desktop\New^ folder^ 3\ %%F IN (folder\*.*) DO (
    MOVE %%F C:\Users\user\Desktop\New^ folder\
)
PAUSE
```

But it brings out a syntax error.
However, When I ECHO %%F, it shows the full path of each file correctly.

What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use quotations around literal strings containing spaces.

```
@ECHO OFF
FOR /R C:\Users\user\Desktop\New^ folder^ 3\ %%F IN (folder\*.*) DO (
    MOVE "%%~F" "C:\Users\user\Desktop\New folder\"
)
PAUSE
```

Comment: It worked like a charm, mind explaining what the '~' means exactly, and why can't I use '^' in the second parameter?

Comment: @bruneti12 The tilde `~` removes (if any) the surrounding quotations from the variable.  The reason you cannot just escape `^` the spaces is because MOST programs are very strict about using spaces as their parameter delimiters.  Therefore if you want a whole path, containing spaces, sent as a single parameter to the move command; it must be within quotes.  For more information on variable modifiers see `call /?`.  Here are some great batch reference sites: http://www.robvanderwoude.com/ and http://ss64.com/